# have a question in sql in coursera. the following code is showing an error

Tags: sqlite, coursera-api

question-Write and run a query, with no starter code or hints to answer this question: What is the step for Union Code 990 and a Set ID of SFMTA or COMMN?
name of the table- salary_range_by_job_classification
my answer code-

```
SELECT STEP,Union_Code,Set-ID
from salary_range_by_job_classification
where (Union_Code=990) and 
(SetID='SFMTA' or 'COMMN')
```

Comment: Did my answer help you with your issue?

Comment: If my answer solved your issue, you may want to put a closure to your question by clicking on the tick mark by the answer to mark it accepted. It's totally your choice, though.

Comment: @zedfoxus i am sorry. Yes your answet helped, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are pretty close. Change your query to:

```
SELECT STEP, Union_Code, SetID
from salary_range_by_job_classification
where Union_Code=990 and SetID in ('SFMTA', 'COMMN')
```

You can also write it like so:

```
SELECT STEP, Union_Code, SetID
from salary_range_by_job_classification
where Union_Code=990 and (SetID = 'SFMTA' or SetID = 'COMMN')
```

Just make sure you are using the column names correctly, consistently.